Risk in using Singleton Call forwarding
I have a contract which manages assets.

Users can add transfer ownership of contracts to the contract
Users should be able to call their own contracts without risking other users having access.

I've made the code which looks like so:
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract ContractManager {
    mapping(address => mapping(address => bool)) private ownerToContracts;

    event ContractAdded(address indexed owner, address indexed contractAddress);
    event ContractForwarded(address indexed caller, address indexed targetContract);

    function addContract(address _contractAddress) external {
        require(_contractAddress != address(0), "Invalid contract address");
        require(_contractAddress != address(this), "Cannot add this contract as a managed contract");

        ownerToContracts[msg.sender][_contractAddress] = true;
        emit ContractAdded(msg.sender, _contractAddress);
    }

    function forward(address _contractAddress, bytes calldata _data) external returns (bytes memory) {
        require(_contractAddress != address(0), "Invalid contract address");
        require(_contractAddress != address(this), "Cannot forward to this contract");
        require(ownerToContracts[msg.sender][_contractAddress], "Caller is not the owner of the target contract");

        (bool success, bytes memory returnData) = _contractAddress.call(_data);
        require(success, "Call to target contract failed");

        emit ContractForwarded(msg.sender, _contractAddress);
        return returnData;
    }
}

Logically this seems okay to do, but I'm worried there may be someway to get around the validation.
Assuming the ownership was transferred properly, is this secure or is there a way to bypass?

Well,
Access control is indeed a very important thing.
Your manager seems okay, however the owner and restrictions need to be written directly in the contracts themselves. If the access controls are not implemented in the contract itself, anyone can just call the contract directly without restrictions.
Also know that when you call a contract through an other contract, the msg.sender will be the contract you are sending the tx from.
For the contracts to be secure and be called only through the contract manager you would have to make sure both the contract manager and the owner are registered in the target contract and implement a modifier that restricts correctly.
Maybe as such:
  address immutable CONTRACT_MANAGER;
  address public owner;

  modifier onlyThroughManager() {
    require(msg.sender == CONTRACT_MANAGER &&
           tx.origin == owner);
    _;
  }

  constructor(address _manager, address _owner) {
     CONTRACT_MANAGER = _manager;
     owner = _owner;
  }

  function foo() external onlyThroughManager() {}


Thanks yeah the contract was mostly pseudo code for the example.  But basically provided the contract was added safely.  This should not be a security risk right, since they wont be able to make calls on contracts that the user isn't registered as the owner

You can call addContract with any _contractAddress you like, even one you shouldn't be able to own, so you can easily bypass it.
